# Does My Personal MySQL Server Shutdown When My PC Shuts Down?

Tags: mysql

I have a quick question about MySQL.  I'm currently developing an RPG game for ROBLOX, and I'm going to be using a significant amount of SQL.  What I want to know is: if I shut down my PC, does the MySQL server shut down as well? If so, how can I change this so that my MySQL server will always run, even if my computer is turned off?

Comment: If your machine is off, and the db server is one it, I somehow think it is Shut Down.

Comment: @Drew Wait, so you know for a fact that the MySQL server shuts down, or are you not sure?

Comment: I don't know for a fact because I keep re-reading your title and the body, and as far as I know your Personal MySQL Server is on another box in your basement.

Comment: Servers are meant to up, to be useful for people that aren't asleep atm. They aren't too useful stuck behind a firewall or people trying to get port forwarding to work for a week. Consider having your data in the cloud. The stuff is free or virtually free and on 24/7. You can even tunnel into it or make a web interface. Consider Openshift or many others. I go with amazon ec2. Azure and Google are also top tier. Many players in the middle.

Comment: @Drew Thanks for the feedback.  I'm completely new to using MySQL (I know the language though). So what does Openshift do exactly?  Is it a cloud storage that you were talking about?

Comment: Openshift is a PaaS as compared to IaaS (ec2 for instance). Google "PaaS vs IaaS". Or see [their page on it](https://developers.openshift.com/overview/basic-terminology.html). It has gear scaling and plug-in cartridges for various pre-built functionality / frameworks. It is fantastic for those just starting. It has a free tier. Owned by Red Hat and technically it sits on top of aws ec2 anyway underneath

Comment: My main experience with Openshift was for simple curiosity. Mainly I have helped people get off of it once the server platform can't handle their special needs. So I rip them off and go strait out ec2. But what comes with that is the need for a lot more experience as rolling your own server with IaaS means you own all of the mistakes. A fine trade-off for some, but not recommended for those just starting out. For new people to the cloud, I certainly recommend PaaS. Also definitely check out aws RDS (flat out mysql svr in the cloud, PaaS, and a free-tier)

Comment: I really want to have a chat with the close voter who voted that this should be migrated to dba.stackexchange.com. It'd be totally inappropriate there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: if I shut down my PC, does the MySQL server shut down as well?

A: Yes, the MySQL Server instance (that is installed and runs on your computer) is "shutdown" when your computer the operating system is "shutdown". When the computer is turned off, the MySQL server is not running.

Q: How can I change this ...

A: This behavior cannot be changed. When your computer is turned off, no operating system programs are running on it. This is by design. (Your computer may have some low-level hardware routines, keeping the network card up listening for a WOL packet, etc. But there is no way that the MySQL Server will be running when your computer is off.

If you want MySQL running, then the computer it runs on needs to be powered on and the OS has to be running. A computer deployed in this fashion, as a separate computer that runs continuously, or on a schedule, even when no user is actively logged on our using the computer is often referred to as a "server".

Comment: Thank you for this answer, it's all I needed.