# C# and Mysql how to access database from here to other place

Tags: c#, mysql

I need your help . I 'am trying to build a system . That will monitor our products . It is like a inventory system. Me the user will monitor and edit the products and client can only view the available stocks and put remark if they pulled ot ou . Is there a way i can access the database from here in our office to the other place . Like im on the mall. And im going to access the database to see if the product was pulled out by the client .with out using database cloud . I will be using c# and mysql . Any suggestions on what should i do ? Thank you.

Comment: Setup a dedicated server for your mysql DB in such a case that this is publicly accessible.

Comment: This type of question is off topic here. Please read the rules of posting.

Comment: yah please post it server stack exchange http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39842528/does-my-personal-mysql-server-shutdown-when-my-pc-shuts-down#comment66974659_39842528) down. Might be useful

Answer (score 0):

you need to host your MySQL Database online and needs to be accessible remotely. [db4free.net](http://db4free.net) and [freemysqlhosting.net](http://freemysqlhosting.net) is just two of those [FREE MySQL Hosting](https://www.google.com/search?q=free+mysql+hosting) that are available out there, although free users can only manage upto 5MB of Database. Of course, if you are willing to pay to their subscription plan, you can expand the database limit.